# Problema NaN al operar con números en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hola a todos buenas noches!

Estoy intentando resolver un ejercicio que vi por internet, pero no logro entender por qué las sumas, restas, multiplicación y división de los valores me devuelven NaN como resultado, no logro identificar qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal, si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho!

Les dejo mi código:

```
alert('¡Bienvenido a su calculadora! Se calculará la suma, resta, multiplicación y división de los valores que ingrese.\nSi quiere calcular la raíz cuadrada de un número, ingrese un solo valor numerérico.\n\nPodrá visualizar los resultados en consola.');

let data;
let acc = [];
let sum, subtract, multiplication, division = 0;

const getValues = () => {
    data = parseFloat(prompt(`Ingrese sus valores numéricos.`));
    if (isNaN(data)) {
        alert(`ERROR: Ingrese únicamente valores numéricos!`);
        getValues();
    } else if (Number(data)) {
        acc.push(data);
        let addMoreValues = confirm(`¿Quiere agregar más valores?`);
        if (addMoreValues === true) {
            getValues();
        } else {
            calculate();
        }
    }
}

const calculate = () => {
    if (acc.length === 1) {
        console.log(`La raíz cuadrada de ${acc[acc.length - 1]} es ${Math.sqrt(acc[acc.length - 1]).toFixed(2)}`);
    } else {
        for (let i of acc) {
            sum += i;
            subtract -= i;
            multiplication *= i;
            division /= i;
        }
        console.log(`Sus valores introducidos son: ${acc.join(', ')}.\n\nLa suma de sus valores es: ${sum}\nLa resta de sus números es: ${subtract}\nLa multiplicación de sus números es: ${multiplication}\nLa división de sus números es: ${division}\n`);
        alert(`Sus resultados han sido mostrados por consola.`);
    }
    repeatProcess();
}

const repeatProcess = () => {
    let echo = confirm(`¿Quiere volver a utilizar la calculadora?`);
    if (echo === true) {
        acc = [];
        getValues();
    } else {
        alert(`¡Gracias por utilizar la calculadora pro!`);
    }
}

getValues();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta inicializar los valores `sum`, `subtract` y `multiplication`, solo inicializaste el último que es `division`

Recomendaciones:

1. Preferir usar Number en vez de parseFloat y parseInt. Puedes probar con parseInt("123HTASDK") para que compruebes que pasa.
2. Inicializar `multiplication` y `division` en 1, de lo contrario siempre te va a dar cero

```js
alert('¡Bienvenido a su calculadora! Se calculará la suma, resta, multiplicación y división de los valores que ingrese.\nSi quiere calcular la raíz cuadrada de un número, ingrese un solo valor numerérico.\n\nPodrá visualizar los resultados en consola.');

let data;
let acc = [];
let sum = 0, subtract = 0, multiplication = 1, division = 1;

const getValues = () => {
    data = Number(prompt(`Ingrese sus valores numéricos.`));
    if (isNaN(data)) {
        alert(`ERROR: Ingrese únicamente valores numéricos!`);
        getValues();
    } else {
        acc.push(data);
        let addMoreValues = confirm(`¿Quiere agregar más valores?`);
        if (addMoreValues === true) {
            getValues();
        } else {
            calculate();
        }
    }
}

const calculate = () => {
  
    if (acc.length === 1) {
        console.log(`La raíz cuadrada de ${acc[acc.length - 1]} es ${Math.sqrt(acc[acc.length - 1]).toFixed(2)}`);
    } else {
        for (let i of acc) {
            sum += i;
            subtract -= i;
            multiplication *= i;
            division /= i;
        }
        console.log(`Sus valores introducidos son: ${acc.join(', ')}.\n\nLa suma de sus valores es: ${sum}\nLa resta de sus números es: ${subtract}\nLa multiplicación de sus números es: ${multiplication}\nLa división de sus números es: ${division.toFixed(2)}\n`);
        alert(`Sus resultados han sido mostrados por consola.`);
    }
    repeatProcess();
}

const repeatProcess = () => {
    let echo = confirm(`¿Quiere volver a utilizar la calculadora?`);
    if (echo === true) {
        acc = [];
        getValues();
    } else {
        alert(`¡Gracias por utilizar la calculadora pro!`);
    }
}

getValues();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Eso no lo sabía, creí que de la manera en que los tenía declarados todos captaban el = 0
Sabrías alguna forma de hacer que la división solo arroje dos decimales?? (Como la raíz cuadrada con el .toFixed(2)), porque si agrego .toFixed(2) al console.log de la función calculate() me arroja 0 en consola y tampoco entiendo por qué!
Aún estoy aprendiendo, perdón jajaja

Comment: @JoagCoder Ahí se lo agregué, si te da cero es porque el valor es muy pequeño (menor a 0,01).